# Is the Fixed Point Theorem Extensional?

Tags: logic, computability, proof-theory

Warning: the title refers to the [Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma) (aka Diagonal Lemma) in mathematical logic.

So I know that the Fixed Point Theorem is essentially equivalent to the recursion theorem, which is uniform. Does this uniformity imply that the FPT is extensional (i.e. there is a function, ideally computable, that outputs a fixed point given any formula, and the outputs for logically equivalent sentences are also equivalent)? (If you need a base theory, let's say Peano arithmetic or Elementary Arithmetic.)

Comment: Please explain your downvote if you can. It helps me improve the question.